# How to read file from JAR as file

Tags: java, file, classloader, iostream

I have created executable jar file,  the file is under resources folder

```
    Example.jar
    |
    |__src
    |  |
    |  Main.class
    |
    File1.txt
```

how can we read File1.txt as a file,
   I tried below code

```
ClassLoader classLoader =Main.class.getClassLoader();
File file= new File(classLoader.getResource("File1.txt").getFile());(without slash)
```

and

```
File file= new File(classLoader.getResource("/File1.txt").getFile());(with slash)
```

with slash i amgetting null pointer exception
and
without slash i am geting file name or directory name is incorrect

Comment: it's easier to use the absolute path and not the relativ one

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a "File" instance to read the content of the file, as the others answered, just use the Stream or the URL. 
Note that the path is absolute when using the classloader:

```
 Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fileAtRoot.txt")
```

is equivalent to

```
 Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/fileAtRoot.txt")
```

If you really wanted the file, it wouldn't work in any case: You could get it if it is a file, but when it is inside a JAR there is no File to open, it will only work from eclipse, or if you put a folder instead of a jar in your classpath.

Here is en example :

DISCLAIMER: THIS IS AN ANTIPATTERN, DON'T ACTUALLY USE IT

```
public class SOResourceLoad {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    new SOResourceLoad().run();
  }

  private void run () {
    try {
      URL resource = getClass().getResource("SOResourceLoad.class");
      System.out.println( resource );
      System.out.println( resource.toURI() );
      System.out.println( new File(resource.toURI()) );
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

The result from  Eclipse

```
file:/D:/opt/workspace/examples/target/classes/pdem/stackoverflow/SOResourceLoad.class
file:/D:/opt/workspace/examples/target/classes/pdem/stackoverflow/SOResourceLoad.class
   D:\opt\workspace\examples\target\classes\pdem\stackoverflow\SOResourceLoad.class
```

the result from a jar file:

```
jar:file:/D:/opt/sodist.jar!/pdem/stackoverflow/SOResourceLoad.class
jar:file:/D:/opt/sodist.jar!/pdem/stackoverflow/SOResourceLoad.class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
    at pdem.stackoverflow.SOResourceLoad.run(SOResourceLoad.java:25)
    at pdem.stackoverflow.SOResourceLoad.main(SOResourceLoad.java:17)
```

The stacktrace show us that we can't get the File when we execute the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("File1.txt")
```

However, normaly you store your resources under resources dir inside the project and/or under your jar root. so I would change the structure a bit to put the resources dir under the root of your project and also under the target structure of your jar and then put the File1.txt there. So, the new loading comand would be  something like that:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/File1.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to check your classloader and then load file:

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
if (cl == null) {
    cl = Class.class.getClassLoader();
}
cl.getResourceAsStream("File1.txt");
```